# how to count repeated instances of foreign-key ID in a table

Tags: count, oracle11g, foreign-keys

I want to find out the course title which is offered the most, by counting the `course_id` in the offering table.

**Course:**

```
+-----------+--------------+-----------------+-------------+
| course_id | course_title | course_duration | course_cost |
+-----------+--------------+-----------------+-------------+
```

**Offering:**

```
+-------------+-----------+-------------------+-----------------+-------------------+
| offering_id | course_id | course_start_date | course_location | course_instructor |
+-------------+-----------+-------------------+-----------------+-------------------+
```

I tried the below query and I don't know why but I am getting an error message:

```
SELECT COURSE.COURSE_TITLE,
  OFFERING.OFFERING_ID,
  OFFERING.COURSE_ID
  COUNT (OFFERING.COURSE_ID) as Mostly_Offered_Course
FROM OFFERING
INNER JOIN COURSE
ON COURSE.COURSE_ID = OFFERING.COURSE_ID
```

I am fairly new to oracle and SQL can you point out where I have made a mistake, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT course_title FROM Course WHERE course_id = 
    (
      SELECT course_id FROM
      (
        SELECT course_id, COUNT(course_id) AS course FROM Offering 
        GROUP BY course_id
        ORDER BY course DESC
      ) AS a LIMIT 1
    )
```

This will get the title with most use. Tested on mysql. On MSSQL just remove "LIMIT 1" and Modified "course_id" into "First(course_id)" in the second select.

Comment: Can you help me find the `course_title` which has the most number of offerings, thanks.

Comment: What I want is to get the course title with the most number offerings. `Course_ID` `COU-1054070` has the most number of offerings. so the output must be only the `course_title` for the corresponding `course_id` can you please help me.

Comment: Edited answer above, also tested it on MySQL.

Comment: Hi, I get the following error in oracle11g.

_ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended_

Thanks.

Comment: Adding ";" at the end of the query and use google to convert it to oracle sql since it's mysql query

Comment: I tried googling on how to convert a mysql query to oracle and found nothing useful.